# Chatter post video preview when posting via flow/process

Tags: chatter, visual-workflow

When I manually post to chatter and post a URL (video) I see a preview of the video, I don't get that when I do it via a flow/process - any ideas?

[image: What I get when I post a url manually to chatter]

I need to be able to achieve this same preview when posting to Chatter via automation.

Answer (score 1):

When you post manually to Chatter, it automatically detects url in the content of the post and creates a link message segment for that post. In order to achieve the same result, you need to create the link message segment in your flow/process. If you use Connect API to generate the post, this article has an example to do that.